# data model for performance monitoring for Tableau Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, tableau-api

I have a question in regards to some performance monitoring.

I am going to connect to the Postgres database and what I want to do is extract the relevant information from tableau server database to my very own database.
I am following a document at the moment to perform the relevant steps needed to retrieve the performance information from Postgres, but what I really require to do is set up a data model for our very own database.

I’m not a strong DBA so may require help in designing the data model but the requirement is:

We want a model in place so that we can see how long workbooks take to load and if any of them take let’s say longer than 5 seconds, we are alerted of this so we can go in and investigate.

My current idea for the data model in very basic terms is having the following tables:

Users – Projects – Workbooks – Views – Performance

Virtually we have our users who access various projects that contain their very own workbooks. The views table is simply for workbook view so that we can see how many times a workbook has been viewed and when. Finally performance table is required for the load time.

This is a very basic description we require but my question is simply is there anyone who has knowledge of tableau and data models to help design a very basic model and schema for this? Will need it salable so that it can perform for as many tableau servers as it can.

Thank you very much,

Comment: What is your business requirement for extracting this data into a separate database? have you looked at the (awesome) charts provided by Tableau in Tableau Server? https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/adminview_stats_load_time.htm

Comment: @Aron Our business requirement is to be able to investigate on any workbooks that load slower than usual. With the alerting system, it means we are given quick notification if this occurs. Currently in Tableau this is not in place as we have to dive in and check historical data to see when performance have been slow. This is also a practice task for me to do in terms of setting up data modelling and learning more about tableau

Comment: @Aron Yeah we know about the charts, it's all about building a data model that does similar thing and create our version of the data in MS SQL and then use Tableau to create dashboards based on this with our alerting system

Comment: Tableau stores the data behind the admin workbooks in a PostgreSQL database on Tableau Server. If you want to look at the same data in a different way, you can enable access to the database via tabadmin and connect directly. You also might want to take a look at Tableau's performance recording features and the open source TabMon project before reinventing something new

Comment: @BruceyBandit BTW, there are much easier ways to make your parents proud than getting a PhD. Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an article from the blog of a monitoring tool that I like and maybe it could help you with your monitoring. I'm not an expert in PostgreSQL but is worth to take a look:

http://blog.pandorafms.org/how-to-monitor-postgress/

Hope this can help!